# In my MERN stack application, after sending a post request, why is "res.status(200).json(data)" working but only doing "res.json(data)" did not?

Tags: mongodb, express, post, request

In my MERN stack application, after sending a POST request to my route, I handle it and save an object to mongo. When I was using .then(data => {res.json(data)}) I was getting an empty {} object as a response and nothing was saving to mongo. This seems to be in the express documentation as valid though? This was also in two tutorials I watched where a bunch of people seemed to get their project working and no one mentioned this as a sticking point in the comments. But I had to hunt down .then(data => {res.status(200).json(data)}) and then the POST request would return my object and it would then show up in mongo. Im using mongoose btw. Im not sure if that is important to say. Both times I received a 200 response however the second code was the only one that made my object appear in mongo atlas. Please please help me know why the bottom code with .status(200) worked while leaving this out did not. It's muddling my mind. This is my first time asking a question on here so any answers that are in the form of a question, please don't answer. If this is not enough information for you to go from, please respectfully ignore this post and move on. Yes I have tried to find other information on this. If you have found some that I havent, please respectfully post sources and dont close this question incase it helps others doing beginner tutorials. We have to start somewhere and of course wont be as good at finding resources as those who have been coding for years. Thank you again though to all for constructive answers :)

Comment: I am not using any ayc functions. I'm not sure if I should be or what the benefit of them specifically is. I figured this might be additional helpful information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.